# Remove style from selected span/text in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider this snippet:

```
<div>
     <span style="color:red;">a</span>
     <span style="color:blue;">a</span>
     <span style="color:white;">a</span>
</div>
```

How can you remove style from selected by user text?

---

**Edited:** to add clarifications from OP:

Thank you for your answers!
I had to be more precise. Sorry for that. 
What do I mean by "selected by user text": selected/highlighted with mouse.
I have many divs with spans inside(just like it is below-no extra ids,classes for spans:/).

```
[...]
<div>
 <span style="color:red;">a</span>
 <span style="color:blue;">b</span>
 <span style="color:white;">c</span>
</div>
<div>
 <span style="color:red;">d</span>
 <span style="color:blue;">a</span>
 <span style="color:white;">a</span>
</div>
[...]
```

What I would like to achieve: user selects with mouse "ab", click button(input type=button) which remove style from selected span/spans. Similar behavior like it is in TinyMCE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by *"selected by user text"*, but if you mean that you want the user to be able to click on the text to remove its color, you could do it this way with jQuery:

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/v24fZ/

```
$(function() {
    $('div > span').click(function() {
        $(this).removeAttr('style');
    });
});
```

Note that this will affect all `<span>` elements that are a child of a `<div>`, so better would be to place an ID attribute on the `<div>` to make sure you have the right one.

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/v24fZ/1/

```
<div id="myID"><span style="color:red;">a</span><span style="color:blue;">a</span><span style="color:white;">a</span></div>
```

then

```
$(function() {
    $('#myID > span').click(function() {
        $(this).removeAttr('style');
    });
});
```

Also note that this will remove *all* inline styles. If you only want to remove the color, then do this:

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/v24fZ/2/

```
$(function() {
    $('#myID > span').click(function() {
        $(this).css('color', '');
    });
});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/
- http://api.jquery.com/css/
- http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 1):

> "Remove style from selected by user text"

If you mean selecting by using a click event, it should be something like this:

```
var oldState = "";  //Code is untested, but I've written something similar recently
var $prevDiv;
$('#parentContainer span').click(function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('selected')) //tracking what is currently selected.
    { 
        if($prevDiv != null)
        {
            $prevDiv.removeClass('selected');  
            $prevDiv.attr('style', oldState);
        }
        $prevDiv = $(this);
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        oldState = $(this).attr('style');
        $(this).attr('style', '');

    }
    else 
    {
        //do nothing unless you need some reselected logic
    }
}
```

I think @patrick dw covered the actual api for changing the attribute quite nicely, so I won't repeat it.

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with patrick.

You may want to try the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <span style="color:red;">a</span>
      <span style="color:blue;">a</span>
      <span style="color:white;">a</span>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        $("span").click(function(){
          $(this).removeAttr("style");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```